# Is there a way to make a radio button's background transparent in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I have had quite a lot of fun with the radio button today trying to make its background transparent.

I have tried the following:

```
input[type=radio]
{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

It seems like this is a Chrome issue alone.

I'm about to do my own radio buttons using canvas.
This way i can scale them more easily too.

Comment: Could you please create a jsFiddle demonstrating the working code in  Firefox?

Comment: Id like to know how you would change the color of the bullet if the background happened to be black.

Comment: Bryan: Adding the example to jsfiddle was a good idea. I found that the radio indeed had a transparent background. But a canvas save context operation made the background white in the Chrome browser. See example here: jsfiddle.net/gYTHF/18 ctx.save() on line 65 causes the opaque white background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gYTHF/18/

ctx.save() on line 65 causes the opaque white background color in the Chrome browser